# CSS not styling <a>

Tags: css, html

I am trying to style my `<a>` tags via `CSS` but they are not changing.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Bugs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a.active, a.link, a.visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Not sure why the CSS would not work. The external stylesheet works for the other tags used throughout the page (IE: `<h1>` is styled properly and they are on the same `.css` file)

Comment: The link has none of the classes you specified. Did you mean to use [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)? `:active`, `:hover`, etc.

Comment: Can you please  choose best answer?, thanks

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa of course - sorry I fell asleep before I let me pick one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In addition, links can be styled differently depending on what state
>   they are in.

**The four links states are:**

> 1. a:link - a normal, unvisited link
> 2. a:visited - a link the user has visited
> 3. a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
> 4. a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

**See example below:**

```css
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: blue;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: aquamarine;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: green;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">This is a link</a>
```

**When setting the style for several link states, there are some order rules:**

> - a:hover MUST come after a:link
> - and a:visited a:active MUST come after a:hover

Answer (score 2):

It should be,

```
a:active, a:link, a:visited, a:hover
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style on hover, link and visited use

`a:hover a:link a:visited`

in your css